# move semantic and struct

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function

```
struct foo {
    std::vector<int> v;
};

foo func();
```

will the vector inside *foo* be moved or copied when returning from the function?

Comment: No, it will be moved.

Comment: It totally depends on what happens inside `func`.

Comment: @BoPersson Not quite, as that question is about returning a `vector`, while this is about returning a struct with the default move constructor and a `vector` member.

Comment: @delnan - No difference. The other question is about returning values in general, and covers this case.

Comment: @BoPersson One thing that matters here, which I did not find anywhere in that question, is whether moving a struct without user-defined move constructor moves the members or copies them. I don't doubt this too has been asked and answered before, but the specific question you link to doesn't quite cut it IMHO.

Comment: @delnan - Ok, I don't think the people answering the other question even considered that returning a vector by itself or returning a vector inside a struct could be any different. It isn't.

Comment: @BoPersson: Of course it is different: in one case, you return an object which explicitely defines a move constructor; in the other case, you return an object without any user-defined constructors. The two cases are obviously different, since the latter involves implicitely-defined constructors.

Comment: @Luc - Ok, I just don't see the difference. Answers to the other question say that when returning a vector from a function, it can be moved. And now we have an answer here saying that the vector inside a struct can also be moved - fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It will be moved**.(*)

Since you do not provide an explicit move constructor for your `foo` class, the compiler will implicitly generate one for you that invokes the move constructor (if available) for all the members of your class. Since `std::vector` defines a move constructor, it will be invoked.

Per Paragraph 12.8/15 of the C++11 Standard:

> The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class X performs a memberwise copy/move
>   of its bases and members. [...]

Also notice, that the compiler is allowed to elide the call to the copy/move constructor of your class when returning an object by value. This optimization is called [(Named) Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

(*) *I am assuming here that your use case is to create a local object with automatic storage inside `foo()` and return it.*

Comment: It won't be moved if the `foo` it returns is perhaps a `foo` with static storage duration. There's probably some other cases too. But yes, I agree with you for the case that the asker is probably asking about.

Comment: @sftrabbit: OK, that's correct. I assumed that he wanted to returned a local object with automatic storage. Edited, thank you.

Comment: @BoPersson: I did mention that, although not RVO explicitly. I will do it.